# synchronise grid columns width in defferent grids, or simplest way to unite cells in some table

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 grids width 3 columns, witch have width="Auto". I want to  equate resulting width of the corresponding columns. So i need this rule:

> grid[0].column[0].width =  grid[1].column[0].width = 
>   grid[2].column[0].width
>
> grid[0].column[1].width =  grid[1].column[1].width = 
>   grid[2].column[1].width
>
> grid[0].column[2].width =  grid[1].column[2].width = 
>   grid[2].column[2].width

Is it possible in wpf?

Or: is there another way to bild Table, with possability  to unite cells( in a vertical, and horisontal), where interface of data is fixed?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) and [SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx) properties to make the columns or rows in different Grids share the same width or height

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn"/>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SecondColumn"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="FirstRow"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  ...

</Grid>

<Grid x:Name="Grid2" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn"/>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SecondColumn"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>        
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="FirstRow"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    ...

</Grid>
```